# How to get messages from multiple queues using aio-pika

Tags: python, python-3.x, rabbitmq

I've just started using RabbitMQ using aio-pika, and I have multiple queue names to consume.
So far I use [this tutorial](https://aio-pika.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rabbitmq-tutorial/2-work-queues.html#putting-it-all-together) in `worker.py` but with multiple queue declarations so it looks like this:

```
import asyncio
from aio_pika import connect    

async def main() -> None:
        # Perform connection
        connection = await connect(Settings.RABBIT_URL)
    
        async with connection:
            # Creating a channel
            channel = await connection.channel()
            await channel.set_qos(prefetch_count=0)
    
            # Declaring queue
            queue = await channel.declare_queue(
                "queue_1",
                durable=True,
            )
    
            queue2 = await channel.declare_queue(
                "queue_2",
                durable=True,
            )
    
            queue3 = await channel.declare_queue(
                "queue_3",
                durable=True,
            )
    
            # Start listening the queue with name 'task_queue'
            await queue.consume(on_message)
            await queue2.consume(on_message)
            await queue3.consume(on_message)
    
            print(" [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C")
            await asyncio.Future()
```

The thing is I need to make it flexible to declare queues as many as how many queue names I could fetch from database, so first is my method to declare multiple queues correct, second how to declare queues based on list of queue names?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after some trials and errors, basically the way I declare queues is right, the next problem about declaring queues and consuming dynamically can be done by using looping the query results and use `locals()` to initiate variables dynamically.

```
queues = dict()
   for q in range(0, len(query)):
      queue_name = query[q]['result']
      locals()['queues_{0}'.format(q)] = await channel.declare_queue(queue_name, durable=True)
      await locals()['queues_{0}'.format(q)].consume(on_message)
```